# Phonegap changing orientation on a single page

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

So my issue is I have this app I am creating with phonegap (ios and android) and a couple of the pages need to be landscape the rest should be portrait. I couldn't seem to get this working in just standard phonegap so I tried to use this plugin (cordova-plugin-screen-orientation   https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation) which was recommended a lot, but it kept breaking the rest of my JS (maybe because I am using cordova 5 and the version it recommends is 4)

Thanks for your help

I have searched for this for a while a couldn't find anything that would work,

Comment: It may not be the cause of your issue, but there's a [bug in the Cordova 5.0.0 CLI](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8953) which is causing iOS builds to be set to portrait-only on iPhone

Comment: @DaveAlden Is there any chance this will be fixed?